# Provide quotes for copying in csv from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the data like below :

```
 174 ROAD "O" NW
```

But i want the data like `"174 ROAD ""O"" NW"`

It means if i have quotes present the new quote should be added in sql query

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql):

```
select '"' + replace (col, '"', '""') + '"'
from your_table;
```